# incorrect Username or password when using auto login macro in excel

Tags: vba, excel, authentication, internet-explorer, dom

I know the login credentials are 100% accurate but I receive the message "wrong username or password"?

Sorry I cant give you the login details but I was hoping some one could take a look at the login page here https://grp.controlant.com/user/login.  I have used inspect element to try and understand what is happening but its all a bit of a puzzle to me.

please could someone give me some pointers so I can login in successfully!

I have studied the login page HTML source code and I think it may have something to do with this line:-

```
<p class="ng-cloak" ng-if="loginError">Wrong username or password</p>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden"     value="O9qaspsZWkSDJc2z8hFkGTqT8XAQ2xAY2QcHMpK1w6v_VKw3T-zQ1H8VpoxARDCnGi-Ed2saqXJjwkE7Hsh4RY2kp6pC_AAATZW7vqFynKw1" />
```

Can anyone confirm if I am going in the right direction?

Below is the code I am using.

Thanks!

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub test1()

  Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
  Dim MyURL As String
  On Error GoTo Err_Clear
  MyURL = "https://grp.controlant.com/user/login"
  Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
  MyBrowser.Silent = True
  MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
  MyBrowser.Visible = True

  Do
  Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

  Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
  HTMLDoc.all.UserName.Value = "my_username" 'Enter your email id here
  HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = "my_password" 'Enter your password here

  For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")
    If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
  Next

  Err_Clear:
  If Err <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Resume Next
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What comes to my mind could be a problem with the encoding of the credentials. Are you using any characters that are non ASCII in your credentials?

Comment: Thanks for your comment but all the charterers are fine, there is a @ in the username but this is ASCII.  Though if I copy and past the username after it has been selected from the saved usernames in the dropdown list in the login form into Excel it is hyperlinked, but when I copy and past the username that has been entered via the excel macro it appears as normal text.  its probably nothing but I though it was odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type username and password *manually* and submit the form then request form data is e. g.

```
grant_type=password&username=qwert12345&password=asdfg67890&client_id=FMUI&client_secret=thisisnotverysecretiknow
```

If you assign the values to inputs programmatically, then request form data is

```
grant_type=password&username=undefined&password=undefined&client_id=FMUI&client_secret=thisisnotverysecretiknow
```

As you can see credentials are `undefined`. Also take a look at `<form>` and `<input>` nodes content in developer tools before submit. When the page just loaded form class property is `ng-pristine ng-valid`, inputs class property is `ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty`. After you type username and password *manually* the properties change to `ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse` and `ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched`.

So, it's not enough just to assign values to inputs. I tried even to assign values programmatically and then to change class properties manually by editing DOM nodes but to no avail. The only way I've found is to fire generic change event for inputs.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Login()

    Dim objEvent, objNodeUsername, objNodePassword, objNodeSubmit

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        ' open the page
        .Navigate "https://grp.controlant.com/user/login"
        ' wait until IE and the page are ready
        Do While .Busy Or Not .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        ' wait until the DOM is ready
        Do Until .document.readyState = "complete": DoEvents: Loop
        ' wait until the username input appears
        Do While TypeName(.document.getElementById("username")) = "Null": DoEvents: Loop
        ' support for dispatchEvent was added in IE9
        ' create event object
        Set objEvent = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        ' setup event
        objEvent.initEvent "change", True, True
        ' get username input and assign value
        Set objNodeUsername = .document.getElementById("username")
        objNodeUsername.Value = "qwert12345"
        ' send event to the input node
        objNodeUsername.dispatchEvent objEvent
        ' get password input and assign value
        Set objNodePassword = .document.getElementById("password")
        objNodePassword.Value = "asdfg67890"
        ' send event to the input node
        objNodePassword.dispatchEvent objEvent
        ' get button and click
        Set objNodeSubmit = .document.getElementsByTagName("button")(0)
        objNodeSubmit.Click
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: any ideas on how to combine the login code with this

Comment: The excel web data tool, I created a macro using this method but I always have to login after I run the macro, hence the reason auto login request! but I am unclear how I combine them to make one working auto login and scraping macro.

Comment: This has come as a lifesaver for me, even after all those years. ++

Answer (score 0):

You aren't *actually* supplying the username and password to the fields. To do so replace

```
HTMLDoc.all.UserName.Value = "my_username" 'Enter your email id here 
HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = "my_password" 'Enter your password here
```

With the following (I looked at the HTML source to find the tags' ids

```
HTMLDoc.GetElementById("username").Value = "my_username" 'Enter your email id here 
HTMLDoc.GetElementById("password").Value = "my_password" 'Enter your password here
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction but I still get wrong username ans password, the fields in the form are actually populated in both instances!